# Install Kate with Konsole Terminal plugin in Fedora23

Tags: fedora, konsole, kate

I installed Konsole and then Kate in Fedora 23. How do I get the Konsole (Terminal?) plugin (I want to have a Konsole (or Terminal) window in Kate, at the bottom of the screen)?

Comment: Three points: (a) use `dnf`, (b) don't install the source-rpm (you need a binary-rpm), and (c) you probably should install from repository rather than try to build your own.  Just `sudo dnf install kate-plugins` should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I would just add to install konsole too!

Comment: I overlooked that (because I usually install every terminal emulator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to

- ensure that `konsole` is installed, to use the plugin.
- install the [`kate-plugins` package](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/leap/42.1/oss/x86_64/kate-plugins-15.12.3-15.4.x86_64.html) (not installed by default).

  sudo dnf install kate-plugins

When that's done, the plugins will show up:

[image]

Select the checkbox, click on *Apply* and *OK*.  Then you should see the Terminal icon at the bottom of the window.  Clicking on that starts a shell, as shown:

[image]